# Will the entries be duplicated?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let say I have a `many-to-many` relation in `spring-data-jpa` between `Post` entity and `Post_Tag` entity. 
Now if I persist a post with tags like `java`, `testing`. The post_tags `java`, `testing` will be persisted with the post with a `cascade type` of `persist`. Now if I save another post with tags like `php`, `testing`, will the `testing` post_tag row duplicated in the `Post_Tag` table? Or the previous entry will be used?

Answer (score 0):

It depend upon id. If you have field tagName in Post_Tag entity and used it as id then only it will use previous entry else it will create a duplicate entry.

```
<id name="tagName" type="string">
    <column name="tag_name" />
    <generator class="assigned" />
</id>
```

Comment: so you mean if the name field is primary key then it will not duplicate it??

Comment: @NavjotSingh Yes.

Comment: So basically when it is not a primary key then i will have to first retrieve all the rows and then add them to the post? Am i right?

Comment: There can be any number of fields an entity can have. You have to decide based on what field/fields, you will consider it as duplicate. In your case tagName seems to be a most preferable candidate for primary key. If not, it will create duplicate with tagname.

Comment: Yes, but since we make artificial keys, I would have to undergo the filtering process before persisting a post.

Comment: You can define an id on name and use assigned generator as,
<id name="tagName" type="string">
 <column name="tag_name" />
 <generator class="assigned" />
</id>

Comment: No that is not what I want